# Sum partially overlapping square matrix / array

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, sum

I have two square matrix / array like that

```
## Matrix 1
t1 <- c(2,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1)
column.names <- c("A","B","C")
row.names <- c("A","B","C")
m1 <- array(t1,dim = c(3,3),dimnames = list(row.names,column.names))
m1
  A B C
A 2 1 1
B 1 1 0
C 1 0 1

## Matrix 2
t2 <- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1)
column.names <- c("A","B","D")
row.names <- c("A","B","D")
m2 <- array(t2,dim = c(3,3),dimnames = list(row.names,column.names))
m2
  A B D
A 1 0 0
B 0 1 1
D 0 1 1
```

I need to sum up them (each existing column/row pairs) and to keep all possible combinations, like that :

```
  A B C D
A 3 1 1 0
B 1 2 0 1
C 1 0 1 0
D 0 1 0 1
```

I have to compute this process a lot of times, so I am looking for a fast and lightweight solution.

Any help would be awsome, I am stuck ;)

Comment: how many times are we talking about?

Comment: about 1000 approximately

Comment: do you have 1000 matrices that may have different rownames and colnames?

Comment: yes, among the 1000, some may have same rownames and colnames, some may have partially overlapping, other may have totally different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `xtabs` + `expand.grid`

```
as.data.frame.matrix(
  xtabs(
    p ~ .,
    do.call(
      rbind,
      lapply(
        list(m1, m2),
        function(x) cbind(expand.grid(dimnames(x)), p = c(x))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

gives

```
  A B C D
A 3 1 1 0
B 1 2 0 1
C 1 0 1 0
D 0 1 0 1
```

---

Another option using `igraph`

```
library(igraph)
get.adjacency(
  graph_from_data_frame(
    do.call(
      rbind,
      lapply(
        list(m1, m2),
        function(x) {
          get.data.frame(
            graph_from_adjacency_matrix(
              x,
              "undirected"
            )
          )
        }
      )
    ), FALSE
  ),
  sparse = FALSE
)
```

which gives

```
  A B C D
A 3 1 1 0
B 1 2 0 1
C 1 0 1 0
D 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: Great, it work as well as the previous answer, but is more easy to iterate! Thanks !

Comment: @RPO I added another answer so you can check which one do you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Make `m1` and `m2` of same dimensions by including all the rownames and colnames available in both of them. Replace non-existent value with 0. You can then add both of them together.

```
cols <- unique(c(colnames(m1), colnames(m2)))
rows <- unique(c(rownames(m1), rownames(m2)))

dummy_m1 <- matrix(0, nrow = length(cols), ncol = length(rows), 
                   dimnames = list(cols, rows))
dummy_m2 <- dummy_m1
dummy_m1[rownames(m1), colnames(m1)] <- m1
dummy_m2[rownames(m2), colnames(m2)] <- m2

dummy_m1 + dummy_m2

#  A B C D
#A 3 1 1 0
#B 1 2 0 1
#C 1 0 1 0
#D 0 1 0 1
```